# Inserir Image em um arquivo HTML

Tags: c#, html, image

Estou criando um arquivo HTML e preciso inserir uma imagem que está nos resources para isso estou tentando utilizar o seguinte código:

```
private byte[] turnImageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image img)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }

 System.Drawing.Image img = MeuProjeto.Properties.Resources.Fundo;
 byte[] imgBytes = turnImageToByteArray(img);
 string teste = "<img src="+@String.Format("data: image / png; base64,{0}", Convert.ToBase64String(imgBytes))+"/>";

 sb.Append("<tr>").Append(teste).Append("</TR><br>");
```

porem quando carrego o arquivo HTML sempre aparece que a imagem está com erro, podem me ajudar onde está o erro? procurei em varios exemplos e todos seguem dessa forma.

Mudei para:

```
byte[] imgBytes = turnImageToByteArray(img);
            string imgString = Convert.ToBase64String(imgBytes);
            string teste = @String.Format("<img src=\"data:image/Png;base64,{0}\">", imgString);
```

e agora está aparecendo isso:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

observe que ele esta carregando uma imagem com erro

Comment: Seria bom informar qual o erro para ajudar a elucidar o problema.

Comment: simplesmente nao aparece a imagem é como se ela nao tivesse sido adicionado

Comment: depois de muito procurar, nao estava funcionando pq eu tava colocando como ToUpper e asasim o caminho nao era localizado